# error lnk2019 unresolved external symbol referenced in function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, dll, mfc

Im currently getting the following errors when I compile my code:

```
1>Link:
1>     Creando biblioteca ..\..\..\..\..\9.0\Accesos\Especiales\Enrolar\Win32\Debug\DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI.lib y objeto ..\..\..\..\..\9.0\Accesos\Especiales\Enrolar\Win32\Debug\DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI.exp
1>DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG.obj : error LNK2001: símbolo externo "public: virtual struct CRuntimeClass * __thiscall DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG::GetRuntimeClass(void)const " (?GetRuntimeClass@DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG@@UBEPAUCRuntimeClass@@XZ) sin resolver
1>DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo __imp__BioB_Open sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: virtual int __thiscall DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG::OnInitDialog(void)" (?OnInitDialog@DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG@@UAEHXZ)
1>DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo __imp__BioB_Close sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: virtual void __thiscall DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG::OnCancel(void)" (?OnCancel@DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG@@UAEXXZ)
1>DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo __imp__BioB_GetAPIProperties sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: static unsigned int __cdecl DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG::_ThreadInitializeDevice(void *)" (?_ThreadInitializeDevice@DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG@@SAIPAX@Z)
1>DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo __imp__BioB_GetDevicesInfo sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: long __thiscall DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG::OnUpdateDeviceList(unsigned int,long)" (?OnUpdateDeviceList@DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG@@QAEJIJ@Z)
1>DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo __imp__BioB_OpenDevice sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: static unsigned int __cdecl DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG::_ThreadInitializeDevice(void *)" (?_ThreadInitializeDevice@DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG@@SAIPAX@Z)
1>DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo _cmtfinger_decode@12 sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: void __thiscall DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG::_SaveImage(struct BioBData const *)" (?_SaveImage@DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG@@QAEXPBUBioBData@@@Z)
1>DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo _cmtfinger_get_property@12 sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: void __thiscall DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG::_SaveImage(struct BioBData const *)" (?_SaveImage@DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG@@QAEXPBUBioBData@@@Z)
1>DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG.obj : error LNK2019: símbolo externo _cmtfinger_get_raster@20 sin resolver al que se hace referencia en la función "public: void __thiscall DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG::_SaveImage(struct BioBData const *)" (?_SaveImage@DLL_LSCAN_DEFINITIVA_SI_DLG@@QAEXPBUBioBData@@@Z)
1>
```

There's an original source code that is done in MFC Visual Studio 2012 (.exe) and I have to do with the same code a DLL MFC Visual Studio 2012. I dont understand what is wrong, I've attached to the folder the same .h files and .cpp that are used on the original one. Someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: @carles: Paste your code in editor provided. You cannot attach file here.

Comment: Possible you need go to Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Linker->Input and add the needed `.lib` file to Additional Dependencies.

Comment: @YuriyOrlov it looks like what you said, now another error appeared but all of the above dissapeared. tomorrow i will post it i cant now. thanks to both.